# Comparing 2 arrays of symbols

Tags: ruby, arrays, symbols

I'm new to ruby, and I've been googling for hours, but I can't figure this one out. It looks like it should be really easy so I'm getting pretty frustrated.

I'm working in ruby and need to compare 2 arrays of symbols for a true or false return.

```
array1 = [:a, :c]
array2 = [:a, :b, :c]
```

The comparison I need to do, is to see if array2 includes all the elements of array1.
In this case array2 includes array1, but array1 does not include array2.

I tried:

```
array2.to_s.include?(array1.to_s)
```

Which only returns true if they are in the same order because it needs to convert to a string for comparison. So as is it returns false (not what I'm looking for), but if array2 = [:a, :c, :b] it would be true. Is there a more appropriate way of making this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

venj's answer is fine for small arrays but might not perform well (this is debatable) for large arrays. Since you're basically doing a set operation ("is Set(array1) a subset of Set(array2)?"), it makes sense to see how Ruby's own [Set library](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Set.html) does this. Set has a [`subset?` method](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Set.html#M000891), and taking a peek at its source we see that it's short and sweet:

```
def subset?(set)
  set.is_a?(Set) or raise ArgumentError, "value must be a set"
  return false if set.size < size
  all? { |o| set.include?(o) }
end
```

We could just instantiate two Set objects from the arrays and call it a day, but it's just as easy to distill it into a oneliner that operates directly on them:

```ruby
array1 = [:a, :c]
array2 = [:a, :b, :c]

array1.length < array2.length && array1.all? {|el| array2.include? el }
# => true

array1 << :z
array1.length < array2.length && array1.all? {|el| array2.include? el }
# => false
```

Comment: that's what i'm looking for, thank you very much! I knew there had to be a simple procedure that I just couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -. e.g.:

```
array1 - array2 #=> returns empty array, if array2 include all array1 elements.
```

Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method to the Array class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Array
  def includes_other(arr)
    raise "arr must be an Array" unless arr.kind_of? Array
    return (arr - self).length == 0
  end
end

arr1 = [:a, :c, :e]
arr2 = [:e, :a, :c, :d]

puts arr2.includes_other(arr1) # prints true

arr3 = [:x, :c, :e]

puts arr3.includes_other(arr1) # prints false
```

Comment: also a very interesting approach. I'll have to play around with that.